# How do I catch exceptions when using `flutter drive`?

Tags: flutter, flutterdriver

When using `flutter drive` my tests still pass even when there was a runtime exception in the stack.

For example, adding this code to build(), goes undetected:

```
int? i;
i!.round();
```

Does anyone know how I can fail on this error?

Answer (score -2):

```
try{}
catch(e){print('error: $e')}
```

and if you know the exception then add this way:-

```
try
on
catch
```

Comment: The question is related to surfacing uncaught errors specifically.